# Quester about PL/SQL using SELECT between BEGIN END

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am junior oracle dba and have a question about PL/SQL. May you give me some advice please?
I would like to know that is it possible to put SELECT query into BEGIN ... END with SPOOL.
The purpose of this code is using array content to be the source of SELECT FROM.
Thank you very much for your kind help.
Here is my shell script with PL/SQL code and it's not working:

```
#! /bin/bash
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "sysmonitor/********" << EOF

declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(30);
  array array_t := array_t(
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3'
  );
begin
  for i in 1..array.count loop
    spool test.log
      select * from array(i);
    spool off;
  end loop;
end;
/

EOF
```

After reading the suggestion from the nice people as below, I made some change as below. However, I still don't know how to spool each result in a single file after looping SELECT the tables (DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1,DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2,DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3). May you give me some advice please?

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "sysmonitor/********" << EOF

declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(30);
  array array_t := array_t(
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3'
  );

begin
  for i IN 1 .. array.count
  loop
    select * from array(i);
  end loop;
end;

spool test.log
  select * from array(i);
spool off
exit
EOF
```

If I run the sql code under sqlplus command line, it returs error.
select * from array(i);
                   *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-06550: line 11, column 20:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 11, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
declare
type array_t is table of varchar2(30);
array array_t := array_t(
'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1',
'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2',
'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3'
);
begin
for i IN 1 .. array.count
loop
select * from array(i);
end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Spool is an SQL*Plus command, so you need to put it outside the anonymous PL/SQL block.

Also, SPOOL will redirect output, so you need to print the result of the SELECT. See the answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590826/how-to-create-a-oracle-sql-scrpt-spool-file

Comment: @KlasLindbäck
Thank you so much ~ :D I start to check it now ~

Comment: Excuse me... I guess I got new problem. After looping SELECT the tables (DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1,DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2,DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3), how do I spool each result in a single file?
I tried this as below but it's not working...
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus "sysmon/systex" << EOF

declare
  type array_t is table of varchar2(30);
  array array_t := array_t(
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE1',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE2',
    'DBUSER_UNEW_TABLE3'
  );

begin
  for i IN 1 .. array.count
  loop
    select * from array(i);
  end loop;
end;

spool test.log
  select * from array(i);
spool off
exit
EOF

Answer (score 0):

Spool is SQL command.
It cannot be used inside annonymous PL/SQL block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice! ~ :D
per the advice, can I do that as below?
    spool test.log
        begin
          for i in 1..array.count loop
            select * from array(i);
        end loop;
      end;
    spool off;
/

Comment: If you think this answer has answered your question, then please check the checkbox near to the post.