# Redirection from an sql file to a log file

Tags: oracle, logfile

i have this code into my sql file :

```
IF ((date1-date2)*60*24) > nb_minutes
THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You have passed the threshold');
END IF;
```

I want to write the message of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` into a log file, for exemple `/tmp/test.log`.
I call my sql file from a `file.sh`

Comment: " I call my sql file from a file.sh" - presumably via SQLPLUS. Why not just redirect the stdio from SQLPLUS to your log file? (`sqlplus user:pass@db <your_code.sql >yourlog.txt`)

Comment: I have a crontab where i made my `file.sh` and into `file.sh` i call `file.sql`, i want to put `You have passed the threshold` in `file.log` how i can do it ? or can you explain me more ?

Comment: The standard approach with SQL*Plus is to spool.  Take a look at this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590826/how-to-create-a-oracle-sql-script-spool-file.  Ollie's answer does a good job of displaying how to do this.

Comment: @PatrickBacon it does not work with SQL Developper ? because i tried it but it does not work

Comment: SQL*Plus is specifically designed for robust spooling (for that matter, also SQLCl).  Coding is often about using the right tool for the task.  If you really want to try spooling with SQL Developer, this post looks interesting, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033943/spool-command-do-not-output-sql-statement-to-file

Comment: @PatrickBacon i tried this in my sql developper `set echo off
SPOOL Bibliothèques\Documents\toto.txt    
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;    
SPOOL OFF` but the `toto.txt` does not created

Comment: When I follow Alex's instructions of placing `set echo off
spool c:\test.csv 
select /*csv*/ username, user_id, created from all_users;
spool off;` in a file, test.sql and call that file from SQL Developer, the test.csv file is created.

Comment: @PatrickBacon i tried it in SQLPLUS, it work! not instead of `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;` i have a procedure. I made my procedure in `fichier.sql` when i called my procedure with `@fichier.sql` the SQLPLUS return the next ligne of my end of my file! i don't understand why