# UniX shell script and PLSQL

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, plsql

I want to fetch the record from oracle database in oracle procedure and develop a shell script to call oracle procedure and convert fetched data in .dat file how would i achieve it.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any error you are getting?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want a oracle procedure to to get certain values from a table, then create a shell script using this data and the shell script should convert data in a .dat file?

Comment: @Gerry Yes you got me right. Actually i am new to this so i havent tried yet.but wanted proper direction to do it.

Comment: it will be best if you use an external language like perl. you can use dbms_scheduler to kick of the script and the perl script can do all the work. You can however issue the scheduler to kick of a shell script directly, but perl will be easier and more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Shell script can't connect to database itself.
Some ways to do it:

1. call `sqlplus` in a shell script using spool option. There are question on SO about this subject, for example: [How to create a oracle sql script spool file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590826/how-to-create-a-oracle-sql-script-spool-file)
2. Use UTL_FILE to write to disk from Oracle directly, without shell script.
3. Use another language to connect to oracle and read data and write it to a file(java, python, etc.)